# what is the use of shipping setprice and shipping setcost

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

What is the use of setprice and setcost in shipping carrier?

> ```
> public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
>     {
>         if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
>             return false;
>         }
>
>         /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
>         $result = $this->rateResultFactory->create();
>
>         /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
>         $method = $this->rateMethodFactory->create();
>
>         $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
>         $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));
>
>         $method->setMethod($this->_code);
>         $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));
>
>         $shippingCost = (float)$this->getConfigData('shipping_cost');
>
>         $method->setPrice($shippingCost);
>         $method->setCost($shippingCost);
>
>         $result->append($method);
>
>         return $result;
>     }
> ```

**$method->setPrice($shippingCost);
$method->setCost($shippingCost);**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setPrice()`: This function is used to set the price of the shipping method. This is the amount that the customer sees during the checkout process. This value can be set manually or dynamically depending on the shipping method used, the weight of the products in the cart, or other rules that might be set up in Magento.

`setCost()`: This function is used to set the cost of the shipping method for the merchant. This cost is usually different from the price and is often not visible to the customer. It's used primarily for internal calculations, analytics, and reports.

For instance, if you have a flat-rate shipping method and you want to charge customers $5.00 for it, you would use the `setPrice` function to set the price as $5.00. However, if your cost for providing this shipping method is $3.00 (say, for example, you're paying a courier service), you would use the `setCost` function to set the cost as $3.00. This allows you to track how much you're spending on shipping versus how much you're charging customers.